Can you create a Journey using Salesforce Data entry ussing SSJS in salesforce marketing cloud?
I was wondering if it was possible to use a SSJS script to build a Journey with a salesforce data entry, mapping the columns and any entry criteria all on the SSJS script?
if possible i will run the SSJS in automation studios to build the journey as a 1 off.
Any SSJS scripts would be useful.

You can use the below SSJS code to build the journey, but i believe you need to tweak the code based on your requirements. For that, you can refer to the below help document : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/journey-builder-api-overview.html
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");

var url = 'https://{{Subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions';
var contentType = 'application/json';
var payload = {
    "key": "SSJS-testing-2",
    "name": "SSJS Journey",
    "description": "We are using this journey to learn how to use the Journey Spec in Journey Builder",
    "workflowApiVersion": 1,
    "triggers": [
        {
            "key": "event-key",
            "name": "Starting point for the journey",
            "type": "Salesforce Data",
            "eventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-c204d5ab-543c-56de-f7f2-75c2f9220311",
            "arguments": {},
            "configurationArguments": {}
        }
    ]
};

var payloadString = Stringify(payload);
var authorizationHeader = "Bearer " + {{Access Token}}

var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = [authorizationHeader];


var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payloadString, headerNames, headerValues);

Write('Response Status Code: ' + result.StatusCode + '<br>');
Write('Response Content: ' + result.Response);
</script>

